# Why does LISTAGG in Oracle 12 does not take my delimiter?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, listagg

I am trying to create an array in a single cell using the `LISTAGG()` function.
Below I have the query that I am using to try to achieve the following output.

```
SELECT 
    x, y,
    LISTAGG(VALUE, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VALUE) AS z
FROM 
    MV_SHARED_TABLE
WHERE 
    y = 'multi_MVL'
GROUP BY 
    x, y
```

**Desired Output:**

```
x, y, z (1; 2; 3; 4)
x1, y1, z (1; 2; 3; 4)
```

My problem is that when I run the query, it seems to have the right information except for the delimeter I chose (;).

Instead of that, I just get a simple (,) comma as a delimeter.

This is all happening through DBVisualizer and connecting to an Oracle DB.

Thank you!

Comment: your delimiter is just a semicolon  ;

Comment: @OldProgrammer in the query I am specifying for the semicolon but it returns with the comma instead.

Comment: And where is `z` coming from?

Comment: Can you replicate this in another client, preferably SQL\*Plus? Or do you already think/know it's a DBVisualizer problem? Including sample data and matching results might help too (MCVE).

Comment: @GordonLinoff z comes from the same table as x and y. the return value of VALUE will be renamed Z and it will be an array of strings. The delimiter is the part that is not working.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have not tried using another client but I can do so later when I get the chance!

Answer (score 0):

Works OK for me on 12c:

```
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> create table my_shared_table(x varchar2(10), y varchar2(10), value number);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into my_shared_table
  2    select 'x', 'y', 1 from dual union
  3    select 'x', 'y', 2 from dual union
  4    select 'x', 'y', 3 from dual union
  5    select 'x', 'y', 4 from dual union
  6    --
  7    select 'x1', 'y1', 5 from dual union
  8    select 'x1', 'y1', 6 from dual union
  9    select 'x1', 'y1', 7 from dual union
 10    select 'x1', 'y1', 8 from dual;

8 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> select x, y, listagg(value, '; ') within group (order by value) as z
  2  from my_shared_table
  3  group by x, y;

X          Y          Z
---------- ---------- --------------------
x          y          1; 2; 3; 4
x1         y1         5; 6; 7; 8

SQL>
```

Comment: what is very odd is that once I did a reconnect with the DB the delimiter started working fine. No changes at all.